# How to select records by condition in postgresql , and from this set select records with the same value of some field?

Tags: postgresql

There is a table with million records.

like so

```sql
select c.id, c.mobile_phone, c.last_name, c.email
from user c
group by c.id, c.mobile_phone, c.last_name, c.email
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

takes minutes.

It is necessary to select records with the same **mobile_phone**, and from the resulting selection, select records that have the same **Email**.

for example

I done that:

```sql
select * from (select * from user where mobile_phone = '00222334422222') ou
where (select count(*) from user inr
       where inr.email = ou.email) > 1;
```

and so:

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY email, mobile_phone
        ORDER BY email, mobile_phone) AS Row_Number
FROM (select * from user where mobile_phone = '2225776676788') as "c*";
```

for example

```sql
select * from employee where
        mobile_phone = '75777302722';
```

[image]

the fields shown in Fig. should be in the final data sample.

It's a version

```sql
select * from (select * from employee where
                                          mobile_phone = '75777302722') ou
where (select count(*) from employee inr
       where inr.email = ou.email) > 1;
```

This code does not work on some versions of postgresql.

PostgreSQL 14.7  - it works.

PostgreSQL 13.7 - doen't work.

I get rows with the same phone number, but I can't select only those rows (from this dataset) where the email is the same (at the same time, rows that have **Email** = null **should not be included**)

5 users have the same phone number.
Of these 5 users - 2 have the same **Email** - **they should be included in the final data set**.

Are there any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Have you created any [index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html) on the table? It could significantly improve the performance of your queries

Comment: 1) I would change to `... from c1 join c2 on c1.mobile_phone = c2.mobile_phone` instead of the `... where c1.mobile_phone = c2.mobile_phone ...`. 2) Why `c1.id < c2.id` and not `c1.id <> c2.id`? 3) *Of these 5 users - 2 have the same Email - they should be included in the final data set*. They are included in the data.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver . This is an unfortunate example, I fixed it.

Comment: You seem to be asking for two different things, all 5 rows where the phone number is the same and the 2 rows that also have the same email. Returning the 5  rows will get you the 2 rows as part of the same set. Of you want something other then that you will need to update your question with example data showing your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, mobile_phone, last_name, email
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY mobile_phone, email) AS rn
    FROM user ) user_rn
WHERE mobile_phone = '75777302722'
  AND rn = 2;
```

In the inner query the `row_number()` function assigns a number to each combination of `mobile_phone, email` and the outer query then selects those records with multiple hits (note that rows with `rn = 3` and higher should not be included because `rn = 2` already supplies the combination).

This solution does not use the `count(*)` function, which is notoriously slow. If performance is an issue, you should add an index on `(mobile_phone, email)`. Any table with more than a few thousand records (or, more precisely: with more than a few physical pages for data storage) will benefit from appropriate indexes tuned to the typical queries.

Comment: no. there are more records there, but he shows one. Although the lines have the same phone number, but they have other unique fields. And I need lines that have the same phone number (a certain number) and the same email (it is not known). I showed the example above, it just doesn't work on version postgrtesql 13.7

Comment: however, thank you. Your code really signals that there are duplicates.